# How to pass selected value from dropdown of a jade template to a rest api in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a Jade template which has two dropdowns and a Load button.
My requirement is to pass the selected value from those two dropdowns to my Node API when the Load button is pressed. I am trying the below code:

```
extends layout

block content



    div.container
     h3 <strong>Project</strong> 

        select
         #projects
           each item in projects
            option(value="#{item.project}") #{item.project}

     h3 <strong>Version</strong>

        select
         #projects
          each item in projects
            option(value="#{item.version}") #{item.version}

     a(href="/employee/"+ #{item.project} + "/" + #{item.version} class="btn btn-default")!= "Load"
```

Currently it is giving me the below error:

500 SyntaxError: D:\NodeJS_appls\nodejs-mongodb-crud-table\views\index.jade:22 20| option("#{item.version}") #{item.version} 21| > 22| a(href="/employee/"+ #{item.project} + "/" + #{item.version} class="btn btn-default")!= "Load" 23| 24| Invalid or unexpected token

How can I pass the selected value to my node API ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably unrelated to your question, but the above Pug code generates very invalid HTML markup.

Comment: @sean Thanks for pointing that out, could you please help me on the problem statement?

Comment: @Merc could you please help me here?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how your data looks like but I can give you some hints:

The `select` should look like this

```
select
  each item in projects
    option(value=item.project) #{item.project}
```

The `a` syntax should be this but it will throw an error

```
a(href="/employee/" + item.project + "/" + item.version class="btn btn-default") Load
```

because `item.project` and `item.version` aren't defined there. Obviously outside the `each` loop.

The Template won't automatically take the selected options value.

You have to bind a click event via javascript to that button. Read out the selected values when clicked and load the other page e.g. `location.href="/employee/" + ...`.

Comment: The data looks like {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d80f1e4267949b40edf1c34"),
        "project" : 4,
        "version" : 2
} Could you please help me with the syntax of how to implement the hint, neither I am getting any clear cut document for this nor able to make it work, Thanks

Comment: I have been able to add a button with this statement , but not sure how and where to define the test() -    button(type='button' class=' c-btn-blue c-btn-circle c-btn-uppercase' value="Read More" onclick="test()") clickme